# Shortcut for the start page in a different language

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm having problems figuring out how to set a different start page for the english version of my website. Is there a way to let users who choose to see the site in english get redirected to another page the the default language start page?

Comment: You mean to check the visitor's default browser language and redirect to another page?

Comment: I have a language switch and after the user switches to english i want to redirect him to another page - not the default language start page.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i use realurl to generate human readable urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below typoscript condition:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 1] && [globalVar = GP:L = 1]
page.config >
page.config.additionalHeaders = Location: http://www.typo3.org
[global]
```

where Id should be your home page id and L equal to L value of English. Location equal to required page link.

Comment: Wow thank you. Didnt think about that at all! I just had to change the condition a bit:

`[globalVar = TSFE:id = 1] && [globalVar = GP:L = 1]`